# how to make vertical lines between the menu items or footer item?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

**I want to make footer like this, but I dont know how to draw that vertical line between ABOUT CONTACT etc...
can anyone help?**

Comment: `ABOUT | CONTACT` - or you could use `border-right` or `border-left` css property

Answer (score 0):

you can use border left or border right of css

```
{
    border-left: 5px solid red;
}
```

Comment: <span style="border-right: 5px solid red;"><span/> <span></span>  have you used like this

Comment: please vote for the post so that others would get help tooo,..always welcome

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do this by adding a CSS script. For this particular image that you have shared, it would be something like this:
Your HTML script would roughly be:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <ul>
        <li class="col-md-2">Copyright</li>
        <li class="col-md-2">About</li>
        <li class="col-md-2">Contact</li>
        <li class="col-md-2">Terms of Use</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

And your CSS script will be:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
ul li:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}
```

Hope this helps!